# wxPython - How to generate an event when selecting in a ListBox?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a ListBox with a few options. I would like to generate wx.EVT_LISTBOX when I call SetSelection. I understand that SetSelection does not generate events to prevent problems during initialization. So I have a function

```
def selectItem(self, index):
    self.myList.SetSelection(index)
    event = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_LISTBOX.typeId, self.myList.GetId())
    wx.PostEvent(self, event)
```

I also have a simple function to handle selecting an item

```
def OnSelect(self, event):
    print event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()
```

This will run, but the when using SelectItem(), the event object is None, and thus I get an error when when I try to use GetStringSelection(). How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Is there a better way to do this?

Actually, rethinking this, I probably don't need to generate the event to accomplish what I'm doing, but I'm still curious as to why this isn't working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's happening because you haven't called `event.SetEventObject(self.myList)` when you create your event.

Comment: Thank you. That was obvious. I can't believe I missed it

Answer (score 0):

You did answer your own question, you shouldn't be generating an event at all in the first place but just call some `DoSelect(self, string)` function from both `selectItem()` and `OnSelect()` instead.

Comment: It doesn't generate any events, that's the point. You should not generate any events, except user-defined ones, in your code. Events are something you get, not something you create.